# htaccess mod_rewrite figuring out how to read hypens for variables

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I want to do is create a pretty url like this:

```
/portfolio/city-state/projectname.php
```

So, for example, I could have

```
/portfolio/Mobile-AL/Johnsonsite.php
```

My mod_rewrite rule works just fine as so:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([A-Za-z0-9_']+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9'-]+).php /portfolio-single.php?city=$1&state=$2&name=$3 [L]
```

But the thing is I want to try and use hyphens for spaces in the city name instead of underscores so the url could be:

```
/portfolio/New-Holland-PA/Johnsonsite.php
--or--
/portfolio/Salt-Lake-City-UT/Johnsonsite.php
```

Is there anyway to count from the rightmost / to the left instead, like pull off the 2-letter state first and assume the rest is the city? Or do you know of a better way?

My best regards, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tweak your url matching regex like this:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.+?)-([^-/]+)/([a-z0-9'-]+)\.php$ /portfolio-single.php?city=$1&state=$2&name=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```